# Assuming that $|z|<1$, calculate: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n^2-3n+2){z^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The answer is: $\frac{-2z^2}{(1-z)^{3}}$

When I do it, I get the answer without the minus sign.

So far, I got:

$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n^2-3n+2)z^n
&= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)(n-2)z^n \\
&= z^3 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)(n-2)z^{n-1} \\
&= z^3 \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n-1}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I've seen this exact question asked at least three times in the last 24 hours.

Comment: I think you should roll back that edit, but the previous version leads me to conjecture the sign error it mentioned resulted from you making a mistake in either the first or second differentiation, starting at $1/(1-z)$. Either that, or you mistakenly started the sum in such a place as to think you were differentiating $z/(1-z)$ twice.

Comment: @Opay Tress: please don't edit the question in a way that Significantly change the post, deleting the effort you showed originally is also no good.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{split}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n^2-3n+2)z^{n-1}
&= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)(n-2)z^{n-1} \\
&= z^2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)(n-2)z^{n-3} \\
&= z^2 \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n-1}\\
&= z^2 \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}\\
&= z^2 \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \frac{1}{1-z}\\
&= z^2 \frac{2}{(1-z)^3}
\end{split}

This proof holds for all complex $z$ with $|z|<1$ which means that, in particular, this also holds for all real $z$ with $0<z<1$.  From the task setting itself, in this case the answer must be positive, since only positive terms are added. So if the result is claimed to be $ \frac{-2 z^2}{(1-z)^3}$, this is false.

Comment: A question that has nothing to do with this one : we had answered, both, about 3-4 days ago to a question dealing with a system of equations with 6 variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$ ; this question and its answers are lost from the radar screen. may I ask you if you know why ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  The last modification I had seen about this question was that moderators soft-deleted it because of MSE rule-violation: the question is contained in an ongoing math contest. I guess that the author now has fully removed the question.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for taking time to answer me.